# Link multiple ionic tabs to same view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to have different tabs link to the same view?
Right now I have:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <ion-tab title="Dashboard" icon-off="ion-ios-speedometer-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-speedometer" active="active.dashboard" >
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-app"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Reports" icon-off="ion-ios-pie-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-pie">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-app"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Create" icon-off="ion-ios-plus" icon-on="ion-plus-circled" >
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-app"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Approvals" icon-off="ion-ios-bell-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-bell">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-app"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Settings" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/tab/settings">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-settings"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

However, each one of these tabs are just a different instance of tab-app, the controller gets reloaded and they do not share any properties.

How can I make the tabs share the same view? I'd like to link them together and have the controller act on whatever tab has been selected. Thanks!

**Update, adding routing:**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
  .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html',
    controller: 'TabCtrl'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.app', {
    url: '/app',
    params: {state_location: null},
    views: {
      'tab-app': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-app.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/app');

})
```

Comment: I think your routing would be useful. I'm not very familiar with the ionic-framework but I think you should use a single ui-view: tabs should just change the state.

Comment: Added the routing :)

Answer (score -1):

this is basically same as having controllers to share data.

- you can create a service to share data between them
- you can use a single ui-view and add and remove page from jonic angular API

Comment: This doesn't work, it seems that ionic tabs work different on a native level. It doesn't expose the same API.